# Whats the impact of requiring a package inside a function if the package is already loaded?

Tags: r, require

Are there any adverse effect to including `library`/`require` statements inside of functions that will be called very frequently?

The time used seems rather negligble, but I am calling the function every few minutes and I am wondering if there is any downside to the repetitve `require` calls?
 *note that the function is just a personal util and is not being shared. ie, I am the only one using it*

Incidentally,  any insight as to why `library` is half as slow as `require`?  I was under the impression they were synonymous.

```
  WithREQUIRE <- function(x) {
    require(stringr)
    str_detect(x, "hello")
  }

  WithLIBRARY <- function(x) {
    library(stringr)
    str_detect(x, "hello")
  }

  Without <- function(x) {
    str_detect(x, "hello")
  }

  x <- "goodbye"

  library(rbenchmark)
  benchmark(WithREQUIRE(x), WithLIBRARY(X), Without(x), replications=1e3, order="relative")

  #            test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
  #      Without(x)         1000   0.592    1.000     0.262    0.006
  #  WithREQUIRE(x)         1000   0.650    1.098     0.295    0.015
  #  WithLIBRARY(X)         1000   1.359    2.296     0.572    0.024
```

Comment: if you are the only person using it , Why not to remove require/library and call it outside the function? taht's said, Inside a function I would use `require` because it returns a warnings not an error.

Comment: Would the speed difference have to do with `library` invisibly returning a list of available packages while `require` just returns a logical `TRUE/FALSE`? I just read that in `?library`, but am no expert on this topic.

Comment: It's bad practice to use `library()` or `require()` inside a function, because it makes it hard to tell what packages code needs. They should either be outside or in package DESCRIPTION. I wouldn't worry so much about the performance implications (and if you did `microbenchmark` gives you better data to go on).

Answer (score 13):

`require` checks whether the package is already loaded (on the search path)

using

```
loaded <- paste("package", package, sep = ":") %in% search()
```

and will only proceed with loading it if this is `FALSE`

`library` includes a similar test, but does a bit more `stuff` when this is TRUE (including creating a list of available packages.

`require` proceeds using a `tryCatch`  call to library and will create a message .

So a single call to `library` or `require` when a package is not on the search path may result in `library` being faster

```
system.time(require(ggplot2))
## Loading required package: ggplot2
##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.08    0.00    0.47 
detach(package:ggplot2)
system.time(library(ggplot2))
##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.06    0.01    0.08
```

But, if the package is already loaded, then as you show, `require` is faster because it doesn't do much more than check the package is loaded.

The best solution would be to create a small package that imports `stringr` (or at least `str_extract` from stringr

Comment: (+1) However, the difference between the two is not that high. Its in the order of 0.01 seconds on my laptop. And `require` sometimes loads faster than `library`.

Comment: @Arun --- interesting. I've qualified my statement to "*may* result in library being faster"