# R: "Object of type 'S4' is not subsettable" when using foreach loop

Tags: r, foreach

I deal with some shapefiles and rasters.

When I execute my script line by line (or part by part), everything runs as expected. However, if I execute it as a whole (either source it or STRG+A and then STRG+ENTER), it throws an error in the following section:

```
# ... some code

list = list()

list = foreach(i = seq(from = 9, to = 80, by = 5)) %dopar% {

    df[which(df@data$column.name > i), ] 
} 

# ... some code
```

Error message: `Error in { : task 2 failed - "Object of type 'S4' is not subsettable"`

Where `fishnet` is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. Code subsets my SpPolDaFr so I get 15 subsetted SpPolDaFr written in the list.

I was thinking of maybe being `foreach` the reason. However, I have other `foreach` calls a priori which run fine. I do the `doParallel` loop because my SpPolDaFr is 11 GB in size to speed things up.

Comment: What do you mean "line by line" ?  What is `fishnet` and have you verified that `fishnet@data` in fact contains a list element with that easily mis-typed name?   BTW it looks like you're just doing a histogram on the data; no real need for a dopar or a loop.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft:  "Line-by-line" means that I only execute parts of my script which belong together. I generalized my code for you. No typo in the call because it works if I only execute this code presented in my question. However, if I source the script, it throws the error message shown above. I don't do a histogram, I just subset a very large SpPolDaFr fifteen times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You usually get this kind of error when the workers haven't loaded the package that defines the class of one of the variables. If the class of "df" is "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" which is defined by the "sp" package, then you should use the foreach `.packages="sp"` option so the workers will be able to properly operate on "df".

Comment: Sorry for late response, had to recover my old script as I used an lapply workaround in practice. However, **loading packages in the foreach options** is the solution! Afterwards my script runs without the error and I can even source it. Thanks! I will update the question title to better address the issue here.

Comment: @pat-s Not sure, if that's efficient I reckon that, in effect, you will be running multiple checks if the desired package is loaded *(which are redundant as you loading it any way),* [relevant discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15259042/1655567).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest using different cluster type when registering the multithreading. Unlike the default type, `FORK` creates a copy of the process. There's no need to specify the packages, but `FORK` is only available on Unix. The code should look like this:

```
cl <- makeCluster(N_CORES, type = "FORK")
registerDoParallel(cl)  

list = foreach(i = seq(from = 9, to = 80, by = 5)) %dopar% {
    df[which(df@data$column.name > i), ] 
} 

stopCluster(cl)
```